# How to remove extra spaces from C# ListView Window control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

[Screen Shot Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ACmz.png)

Binding items and ICON image to ListView creates unwanted space, between the Text and ICON. Is  there a way to remove the space. This is .net Win Form app. No spaces in the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to remove extra spaces from a C# ListView control:

1. Use the Trim() method on the strings in the ListView control.
2. Use the String.Replace() method to replace all whitespace characters with an empty string.
3. Use a regular expression to replace all whitespace characters with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, but the space is not in the string, screen shot attached. There is a padding/space between the Item.Text and ImageList (ICON) for that item.

Comment: You can set the <code>View</code> property of the <code>ListView</code> to <code>Details</code> and then set the <code>SmallImageList</code> property to <code>null</code>.

Comment: It has to be List and needs icon.

Answer (score 0):

Your image shows whitespace at the beginning of each string, so the simplest way to do this is via `yourString.TrimStart(' ');` which will remove all leading occurrences of the char you want to remove

Also worth noting that [TrimStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-6.0) takes multiple arguments of chars that it can trim from the beginning, so if you know ahead of time that other leading characters may be a problem, you can pass them in as arguments to process out all

Comment: There is no space , or special char, even though if I change the text to something like below, still I get the spaces.   ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                        //cProdTypeItem.StrName.TrimStart(' ')
                        item.Text = "HELLO";
                        item.StateImageIndex = 0;
                        item.Tag = "k" + cProdTypeItem.StrId;

Comment: In that case, this is very likely a front end and/or code behind issue and you will need to post your code snippets of the relevant UI elements here. Hard to tell what could be the cause of the problem without knowing that